# Cassandra seed values in a three node datacenter

Tags: cassandra

We are deploying our application to production this month and our stack will include a 3 node, single datacenter Cassandra version 1.2 cluster.  In anticipation of this, we have been getting our initial Cassandra.yaml settings worked out.  While doing this I ran into a interesting situation for which I haven't been able to find an answer.

This has to do with setting the -seeds parameter in each of the nodes Cassandra.yaml files.  All of the reading I've done say it is best practice to:

1. Have at least 2 seeds per datacenter.  This makes sense so that one of the nodes can come down and other nodes can be seeded by the second seed.
2. These two seeds should be the same for all (in our case 3) nodes.

In the deployment I tested this on, I started out with all three nodes having a single seed, node 1's IP address.  My intention was to change the seeds of all three nodes to the IP address of node1 and node2.  First I did node 3 by:

- decommissioning the node.
- Shutting down Cassandra.
- changing the -seeds value to ip_node1,ip_node2
- starting up Cassandra.
- running nodetool status to ensure the node was added back to the cluster.

Next I did node 2, following the exact same steps I did for node 3.  But something unexpected happened.  When I restarted Cassandra on node 2, it did not join the existing ring.  Instead it started its own single node ring.  It seems pretty obvious that of the two seed parameters I passed it, it used its own IP address and thus believed it was the first node in a new ring.

I was surprised Cassandra didn't select the seed argument of the other seed value I passed it (node 2's). The only way I could get it to join the existing datacenter was to set its seeds to one or both of the other nodes in the cluster.

An obvious work around to this is to configure each of my three nodes seeds value to the IP addresses of the other two nodes in the cluster.  But since several sources have suggested this isn't a "Best Practice" I thought I'd ask how this should be handled.  So my question is:

1. Is it normal for Cassandra to always use its own IP address as a seed if it is in the seed list?
2. Is configuring the cluster the way I've suggested, which goes against best practice a huge issue?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the solution to your question but did you compare all your **`cassandra.yaml`** files?

They should all be the same, apart from things like `listen_address`.

Is it possible you might have had a whitespace or typo in the `cluster name` also?

I just thought I'd mention it as something good to check.